# Usage of BigIntegers and to the power off i

Tags: java, biginteger

I found out longs wont cut it, as the numbers I'm calculating are to huge to fit. I'm struggling with the concept of BigInts.

Lets say I have the following equation to perform.

```
int p = 11549
int n = 252817
```

The equation is as follows.. : ( number * p )^ (to the power of i)%n .

With longs I just did :

```
long number;
long p;
long n;
long temp;
long total;

for (int i=0; i<6;i++) {
   temp = numer*Math.pow(p,i);
   total += temp;
}

total %= n;
```

But when i use Math.pow on I the numbers get to huge to use this method, and I need to use BigIntegers. I Just dont understand how I can do it. Right now I got this : (Missing the % until i can figure out the power off statement.)

```
long temp;
long p;
BigInteger opphoyd;
BigInteger mod;
for (int i=0;i<6;i++) {
   temp = number * p;
   opphoyd = BigInteger.valueOf(temp);
   mod = BigInteger.valueOf(i);
   mod.add(opphoyd.pow(i));
   mod.add(opphoyd);
   System.out.println(mod);  
}
```

But its not working at all, could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BigInteger's add method (and most of the other methods) does not modify the BigInteger it is called on. Instead it returns a new BigInteger.

So you would need to do:

`BigInteger sum = mod.add(opphoyd);`

Take a look at the [javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html), it will be very helpful when working with BigInteger.

```
long temp;
long p;
BigInteger opphoyd;
BigInteger mod;
for( int i = 0; i < 6; i++ ) {
   temp = number * p;
   opphoyd = BigInteger.valueOf(temp);
   mod = BigInteger.valueOf(i);
   BigInteger sum = mod.add( opphoyd.pow(i));
   sum = sum.add(opphoyd);
   System.out.println( sum );
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I'm almost there.. lets say I have : 
  BigInteger hashone = BigInteger.valueOf(p);  
  BigInteger seconddeg = hashone.pow(i);
  BigInteger hasttwo = BigInteger.valueOf(ascii);
  BigInteger result = seconddeg.multiply(hasttwo);
how would I go about adding result to a new bigint then? The sum = sum.add(opphoyd) confused me.